# How to get checkbox value in multicheckbox onchange event

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, onchange

I have created two custom fields on woocommerce checkout page. First Field is text and second is multicheckbox. I want both fields to show output on same page using Onchange event.

Text Field code is

```
<p class="form-row form-row-wide wooccm-field wooccm-field-wooccm11 wooccm-type-text validate-required woocommerce-validated" id="billing_wooccm11_field" data-priority="50">
    <label for="billing_wooccm11" class="">Other NAME&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
    <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
        <input type="text" class="input-text wooccm-required-field" name="billing_wooccm11" id="billing_wooccm11" placeholder="" value="" data-required="1">
    </span>
</p>
```

I have used this code to display value of text field

```
<script>

document.getElementById("billing_wooccm11").onchange = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
var input = document.getElementById("billing_wooccm11").value;

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = input;
}
</script>

    <p id="demo"></p>
```

It is working and showing value as required. But second field which is multicheckbox is not working

Multicheckbox field code is

```
<p class="form-row form-row-wide wooccm-field wooccm-field-wooccm14 wooccm-type-multicheckbox validate-required" id="billing_wooccm14_field" data-priority="130">
    <label for="billing_wooccm14" class="">PROGRAMME&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
    <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"> 
        <span class="woocommerce-multicheckbox-wrapper" data-required="1">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="billing_wooccm14[]" value="one"> One</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="billing_wooccm14[]" value="two"> Two</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="billing_wooccm14[]" value="three"> Thress</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="billing_wooccm14[]" value="Four"> four</label>
        </span>
    </span>
</p>
```

I want to display text of checkbox just like text field. So when any checkbox is checked its value should appear and if user unchecked it, its text should also disappear.

Comment: Working on a solution, seems pretty simple

Comment: @Nanoo Yes it might be simple but unfortunately I am unable to do it.

Comment: I can help you out soon - I did have an answer, but assumed Ess' answer was suitable.

Comment: No that didn't worked. If you have an answer please post here as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have a way to go about this, let's say we have these two input checkbox buttons. first, you must iterate through the buttons you have using the name attribute.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="myinput" name="input_check" value="one">
<input type="checkbox" class="myinput" name="input_check" value="two">
```

then for the js code:

```
document.querySelector('[name="input_check"]').onchange = function() {myFunction()};
function myFunction(){
var checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('.myinput');
for(let i=0; i<checkbox.length; i++)
  if (checkbox[i].checked)
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHtml = checkbox[i].value;
}
```

I hope this works for you :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't worked for me. I don't have  `class` in   `input` fields. I am using plugin to generate these fields so can't have class or id.

Comment: you can use the name instead

Comment: replace it with this 
var checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('[name="input_check"]');